# How do update nested object field with useReducer?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

I am new to using useReducer, I need to write a reducer function for this. These will be hooked into text fields and I am trying to update the state this way.

```
    const [registerReq, updateRegister] = useReducer(registerReducer, {
    user: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      jobTitle: "",
      email: "",
      phone: ""
    }
  }
  );
```

I can do it fine with a single object, but I cannot do it with a nested object.

here is the type I am using

```
export interface RegisterReq {
```

user: {
firstName: string
lastName: string
jobTitle: string
email: string
phone: string
}
}

```
const registerReducer = (state: RegisterReq, update: Partial<RegisterReq>) => ({
  ...state,
  ...update
});
```

updater function

```
const updateFirstName: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (evt) => {
updateRegister({ user: { firstName: evt.target.value }})
```

};

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: yes hold on I will show you what I got

Comment: here is the type and reducer and updater function I have that is throwing an error

Comment: export interface RegisterReq {
  user: {
    firstName: string
    lastName: string
    jobTitle: string
    email: string
    phone: string
  }
}